# Xstream: removing class attribute

Tags: java, attributes, annotations, xstream

How do I remove the *class=”Something ”* attributes in Xstream .

I use Xstream with annotations

Comment: Where are you getting class="..." exactly? Can you post some generated XML?

Comment: http://markmail.org/message/t33x7hswlwsk766i

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed the problem is not as clearly phrased as it should. My guess is that you are using a non-standard collection or using a field of an interface type for which XStream needs to store the actual class.

In the second case you can just use alias:

`xstream.alias("field name", Interface.class, ActualClassToUse.class);`

See http://markmail.org/message/gds63p3dnhpy3ef2 for more details.

Comment: <edit> I had a similar problem and this turned out to be the problem. I was worried that I would have to use alias javacode instead of annotations, but they turned out to complement eachother nicely as I can determine the actual class to use at runtime.

Comment: Is there a spring oxm alternative available for this?

Answer (score 22):

I read its code and found if your class is not `mapper.defaultImplementationOf(fieldType)` , it will add the default class attribute for you, unless the class attribute name is null;

So, set this can remove the class=”Something ” attributes

```
 xstream.aliasSystemAttribute(null, "class");
```

Comment: Is there a spring oxm alternative available for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use something of this sort to remove the class attribute completely rather than aliasing it with something else:

```
private String generateResponse(final XStream xStream)
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    xStream.marshal(this, new PrettyPrintWriter(writer) {
        @Override
        public void addAttribute(final String key, final String value)
        {
            if (!key.equals("class"))
            {
                super.addAttribute(key, value);
            }
        }
    });
    return writer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This attribute is shown, at least, when it's not obvious which class shall be used. Usage of interface is an example.
In situations like that You can try:

```
xStream.addDefaultImplementation(YourDefaultImplementation.class, YourInterface.class);
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some example output?  I think this usually happens when using Collections. Without seeing the output, my best guess is that you need to register aliases:

```
xstream.alias("blog", Blog.class);
```

See http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html for more in-depth coverage.  Again, paste in some sample output.